# I want to read "local archive" or "In-place archive" from Office 365 with javax mail

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail

I can read INBOX With javax.mail from office 365:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "user@mydomain", "mypass");
Folder[] allFolders = store.getDefaultFolder().list();
for(Folder folder: allFolders){
    System.out.println(" root subfolder: " + folder.getName());
}
```

But, it's not possible to read the "local archive" or "in-place archive" folder. I only read root subfolder: example INBOX

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I am not sure but "local archive" would be on local storage, not on imap server, wouldn't it?

Comment: "local archive" is when archived emails to backup of historical emails or a second storage in the server of office 365. thanks for your help.